# Initializing classes from saved file

Tags: c++, class, constructor, load, save

In Objective-C++, I want my application to be able to save and load files that express the existence of certain C++ objects. For example, a user is running the application and has created objects `a`, `b`, and `c` of classes `A`, `B`, and `C`. The user hits save to create a file that lists these objects in some format. The application should then be able to load from this file and initialize new objects `x`, `y`, and `z` of classes `A`, `B`, and `C` by calling constructors `A()`, `B()`, and `C()`. (This is obviously a heavy simplification of the process.)

What do you think is the best strategy for doing this? Is there any more elegant solution than a big switch statement mapping text to constructors or something along those lines? Would function pointers help me out? I could imagine doing something like having `A`, `B`, and `C` register themselves with the object that owns them, and it stores their constructors with a key somewhere, but I'm wondering if there's something simple that I'm missing.

The big issue here is that there are dozens of classes that must be saved so I want the lightest solution possible.

Comment: Read up on Serialization: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comment I just put on your post, that article states the following regarding Objective-C:

"In the Objective-C programming language, serialization (more commonly known as archiving) is achieved by overriding the `write:` and `read:` methods in the Object root class."

I'm only new to Objective-C myself, but I'm familiar with the concept of serialization. In this case, by overriding those methods, you are making an object of a given type capable of writing itself to a file in a format you specify, and also you are allowing it to set its state by reading its state from a file.

I'm sure Google will reveal a lot of tutorials on this.